# Connecting one Raspberry pi pin to many IR sensors

Tags: raspbian, python, rpi.gpio, sensor, breadboard

I'm currently using pin 3 on my Raspberry pi to run one of my IR sensors. But I need to use 4 IR sensors for the purpose.
 Is it possible to connect all the 4 IR sensors to the same pin using a bread board and be able to differentiate among all the 4 IR sensors when I code for it.
I'm making a Car with 4 IR sensors on all 4 sides, so as to detect any kind of obstacles and move without hitting any objects.
Please help. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Please tell me if you're using analog or digital sensors?

Comment: It is a digital sensor.

Answer (score 1):

No, not connected to a simple digital input GPIO.

Two reasons:

1. You can't differentiate between the sensors.
2. Generally IR sensors actively set their outputs high or low.  If a sensor raises an alarm its output will be overridden by the other sensors denying the alarm.

To use multiple sensors on the same GPIO they need to be part of a bus.  Perhaps search for IR sensors which use the Dallas 1-wire bus or the I2C bus.

Answer (score 0):

Using digital sensors there is no way to differentiate between the 4 sensors on the same pin.